# Tableau - Dynamically Change Available Filter Options Based On Other Filter Value

Tags: filter, dynamic, tableau-desktop

I have three filters: Region, Location, and Department. When I select a specific region, I want only the locations and departments applicable to that region to appear in the Location and Department filters. I can make it happen (sort of) once by selecting "Show Relevant Values Only" or "Show Context Values Only" which allows for the other two filters to have only relevant values checked (other values still appear but are unchecked), but as soon as I change the region filter, all values are checked.

I also want to apply this dynamic filtering for all combinations - i.e. if I choose one location, I want only the corresponding region to appear in the Region filter and corresponding departments to appear in Department filter.

Any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out!

So each filter box you create (ie. on your sheet when you click "Show Filter" or in a Dashboard when you click to add the filter to the dashboard) you need to click the down arrow and select "Show Relevant Values Only". This is the only way to keep it dynamic (cascading) on the Dashboard or sheet apparently.

Comment: Show relevant values only is one solution to have the filter choices populated based on the other filter settings. If you have many filters shown, you can add a delay for your dashboard to reset as it then has to requery to repopulate multiple filter choices everytime you set any filter.. If your fields are in a hierarchy, then there is a similar, more efficient option, to restrict choices based on the filters in the same hierarchy.

Comment: If you have a filter that you'd like to apply earlier than all the others, you can add that filter to the context. Using context filters can sometimes be an efficient way to affect the whole dashboard. So try making Region a context filter, and setting the others to all in database. Like all performance experiments, test